# Ruby/Rails - Parse JSON and split object to convert to datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, datetime, split

I have the following code:

```
page = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://www.enhancetv.com.au/tvguide/rss/melbournerss.php')).body rescue nil
show_info = Hash.from_xml(page).to_json
puts show_info
```

Which outputs the following JSON:

```
{"rss":{"version":"2.0","channel":{"title":"EnhanceTV Melbourne TV Guide ","description":null,"link":"http://www.enhancetv.com.au","lastBuildDate":"Wed, 21 Dec
2011 10:25:55 1000","generator":"FeedCreator 1.7.2","item":[{"title":"Toasted TV - TEN - 07:00:00 - 21/12/2011","link":"http://www.enhancetv.com.au/tvguide/","d
escription":"Join the team for the latest in gaming, sport, gadgets, pop culture, movies, music and other seriously fun stuff! Featuring a variety of your favou
rite cartoons."},{"title":"Totally Wild - TEN - 08:00:00 - 21/12/2011","link":"http://www.enhancetv.com.au/tvguide/","description":"The Totally Wild team brings
 you the latest in action, adventure and wildlife from Australia and around theglobe."},{"title":"Explore: Africa&apos;s Rift Valley - SBS ONE - 19:30:00 - 21/
12/2011","link":"http://www.enhancetv.com.au/tvguide/","description":"Simon Reeve leads a team of journalists on a spectacular journey down East Africa&apos;s R
ift Valley. From the tiny country of Djibouti, which is the centre of America&apos;s military presence in Africa, to the wide open plains of Kenya, the team enc
ounter awe-inspiring landscapes, rich culture and amazing wildlife."}]}}}
```

First of all I'd like to actually be able to loop through each of the items.

This is what I have so far, however it's throwing an error. I'm not entirely sure how to even loop through the parsed JSON properly:

```
result = JSON.parse(show_info) # convert JSON data to native ruby

result["channel"].each do |a|
    puts a['title']
    puts a['description']
    puts a['link']
end
```

This gives the following error:

```
scraper.rb:118:in `<main>': undefined method `each' for "rss":String (NoMethodEr
ror)
```

I'd then want to be able to do a `split` on the `"title"` so I can convert the time and date into a `DateTime` object to use later.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass` error makes more sense to me for that JSON. Are you sure that that error message came from the code and that JSON?

Comment: Since the original source is in xml how about using Nokogiri to do the parsing and whatever else instead of converting the contents time and time over.

Comment: @muistooshort Yeah, it's definitely coming from that particular line of code and that JSON.

Comment: @KassymDorsel Will take a look at Nokogiri.

Comment: You've already converted the XML to a hash structure. Why round-trip through JSON?  And shouldn't it be result["rss"]["channel"] since rss is the top level element in the hash?

Comment: @graza Point taken, going with nokogiri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use Nokogiri to parse the XML instead of converting the XML to JSON.

Thanks for your help.